# How to right align table header in tabulator?

Tags: javascript, html, tabulator

In JavaScript, I'm calling an API and using tabulator and trying to display the  data in JavaScript. I want to custom alignment some of left and some of to right. When applying align property, it is aligning only table data not table headers, I want custom alignment of table header. Please someone help me.

Part of the code:

```
columns: [
    { title: "Date", field: "Date", sorter: "date", align: "left", bottomCalc: function (values) { return "Grand Total"; } },
    {
        title: "Transaction Count", field: "TransactionCount", sorter: "number", align: "right", bottomCalc: "sum"
    },
    {
        title: "Credit Card", field: "CreditCard", sorter: "number", align: "right", visible: false, formatter: "money", bottomCalc: "sum", bottomCalcParams: { precision: "2" }
    },
    {
        title: "Cash", field: "Cash", sorter: "number", align: "right", visible: false, formatter: "money", bottomCalc: "sum", bottomCalcParams: { precision: "2" }
    },
    {
        title: "No Charge", field: "NoCharge", sorter: "number", align: "right", visible: false, formatter: "money", bottomCalc: "sum", bottomCalcParams: { precision: "2" }
    },
    {
        title: "ACH", field: "ACH", sorter: "number", align: "right", visible: false, formatter: "money", bottomCalc: "sum", bottomCalcParams: { precision: "2" }
    },
    {
        title: "Total", field: "Total", sorter: "number", align: "right", formatter: "money",  bottomCalc: "sum", bottomCalcParams: { precision: "2"}
    }
    ],
```

Comment: where is the html ?

Comment: i'm using an empty division to display the data like below:   reportTable = new Tabulator("#ReportTableDiv", {   renderComplete: function () {
            DownloadReportAsFile();
        },

Comment: brother i can't help your without having a look into your html code!

Comment: add your complete required code.

Comment: brother nothing is there in html only Empty Division and linking the Tabulator script/plugin file in header section.  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tabulator/4.1.5/css/tabulator_modern.css" rel="stylesheet">

Comment: so i'm sending division id and API DATA as parameters to the tabulator and it creates the data and showing in that empty division. i aligned columns as above code(mention in with question) but it aligning only table data not table headers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there's a built-in option at this point, but it can be achieved using some simple css.

Add a custom CSS class to the colums with right-aligned headers in your column definition:

```js
{ title: "Transaction Count", cssClass: "rightAlignedHeader", (...) },
```

Then define right text-alignment for this class in css, but limit it to sub-elements of .tabulator-header

```css
.tabulator-header .rightAlignedHeader {
  text-align: right !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var coldefs = tableR.getColumnDefinitions();
for (var i=0;i<coldefs.length;i++) {
    coldefs[i].align = 'right';
}
tableR.setColumns(coldefs);
```

Comment: Please give an explanation of your code so others can learn from it.